# Magento <A> links losing images

Tags: magento

I'm trying to implement an automatic advanced search which the user would invoke by clicking on an image.

For example what I'm trying to get is

```
<span>
    <a href="catalogsearch/advanced/result/?price[from]=0&price[to]=10">
        <img src="....etc" />
    </a>
</span>
```

but for some reason the image won't show, either in the editor preview or on the actual page, even though image inspector shows it to be exactly as I'd expect.

If I change the word 'advanced' to 'bdvanced' then it works as expected.  I can also change it to 'a' and it works, but 'ad', 'adv', etc. all cause it not to work!

What on earth is going on here? 
If it's a 'design feature', how can I get round it?

I also tried changing letters or '/' to equivalent &# codes but Magento is 'clever' enough to convert them back again.

Comment: does the image show a broken image icon or does the image not appear at all? Could the CSS be at play?

Comment: There's no image at all.  There are two other such links currently just set to '#' and they both show. I'm pretty sure it's not CSS related.  If I paste that code into a static box and if the 'a' of advanced is there, no image shows... and that's not even getting as far as saving it!  This is mighty strange

Comment: I'd be grateful if someone can try this test...

Comment: I'd be grateful if someone can try this test...
Go to add a static block and switch editor to 'hide' so you enter html and enter something like `<a href="ad"><img src="..some image" /></a>` - click show/hide editor and it should show OK.  
Click editor again and change `<a href="ad">` to `<a href="/ad">` and click back.  In my case the image vanishes!  How about yours?

Comment: It's looking like this may be a browser issue.  When I tried it on another machine there was no problem so I think it must be down to my environment in some way.  Very strange.